# Display rss xml index in html

Tags: php, html, rss

I am adding an RSS feed to my website.  I created the RSS.xml index file and next I want to display its contents in a nicely formatted way in a webpage.

Using PHP, I can do this:

```
$index = file_get_contents ($path . 'RSS.xml');
echo $index;
```

But all that does is dump the contents as a long stream of text with the tags removed.

I know that treating RSS.xml as a link, like this:

```
<a href="../blogs/RSS.xml">
  <img src="../blogs/feed-icon-16.gif">Blog Index
</a>
```

causes my browser to parse and display it in a reasonable way when the user clicks on the link.  However I want to embed it directly in the web page and not make the user go through another click.

What is the proper way to do what I want?

Comment: https://github.com/jewelhuq/Online-News-Grabber/tree/master/worldnews  Follow this . hope you will get your answer.

Comment: Personally I might be tempted to use XSLT - either in javascript or php as it'll give you the ability to govern the aspects from the rss feed get displayed and how.

Comment: Use XSLT for what?  Sorry for ignorance, I started today with RSS feeds.  I need the rss XML file to be standard and recognized by aggregators.

Comment: @jewelhuq  I was just looking through your code but am not finding where you load or parse an RSS xml file.  Any hints?

Comment: check out : https://github.com/jewelhuq/Online-News-Grabber/blob/master/worldnews/library.php page specially getData function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
 include_once('Simple/autoloader.php');
    $feed = new SimplePie();
    $feed->set_feed_url($url);
    $feed->enable_cache(false);
    $feed->set_output_encoding('utf-8');
    $feed->init();

     $i=0;
    $items = $feed->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
    $i++;
   /*You are getting title,description,date of your rss by the following code*/
    $title = $item->get_title();
    $url   = $item->get_permalink();
    $desc  = $item->get_description();
    $date  = $item->get_date();
    }
```

Download the Simple folder data from : https://github.com/jewelhuq/Online-News-Grabber/tree/master/worldnews/Simple

Hope it will work for you. There $url mean your rss feed url. If you works then response.

Comment: Thanks.  I gave you a +1 but it doesn't quite answer the question.  I discovered a solution while you were doing your post and have a created a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it's simple by using the PHP xml parer function:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file ($path . 'RSS.xml');
$channel = $xml->channel;
$channel_title = $channel->title;
$channel_description = $channel->description;

echo "<h1>$channel_title</h1>";
echo "<h2>$channel_description</h2>";

foreach ($channel->item as $item)
{
  $title = $item->title;
  $link = $item->link;
  $descr = $item->description;

  echo "<h3><a href='$link'>$title</a></h3>";
  echo "<p>$descr</p>";
}
```